# Must these two vector spaces always be isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the cardinality of $V$ is the same as the cardinality of $W$. Must $V$ and $W$ be isomorphic?

Comment: What is the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}?$ What is the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}^2?$

Comment: You could have two vector spaces of the same cardinality but different dimension so not isomorphic